# Renaming default folders in Blazor project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to rename the `Shared` folder in my Blazor Server project to `Components`, how can I do that properly? It seems like namespaces are based on folder names but there must be a way right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just rename the Folder to Components. That does indeed change the namespace, edit the `_Imports.razor` file like this:

```
@*@using MyApp.Shared*@  -- remove this line
@using MyApp.Components
```